# WP8 - App layout completely messed up when there is an incoming call

Tags: c#, xaml, events, user-interface, windows-phone-8

I have a problem with the app I'm developing.
I noticed that if I open the app while I have a phone call active, or if I am in the app and I receive a call, the layout gets completely messed up.
I mean, the panorama itself remains ok, and so do the elements and the controls that are outside of the Panorama control (like some rectangles/textblock I have that remains still when I change panorama page).

But all the elements inside the panorama pages gets messed up, it's like they remain where they were, but the whole app UI slides underneath them, so they end up resulting in the wrong position.
Or the textblocks get "cut", like their margins remains still and the text inside them slides towards the bottom of the screen.

Is there a way to prevent this from happening?
I don't know, some setting to say "if you get a call, don't mess with the app UI" :D

I just want the call banner to cover the upper part of the screen, *without* the app UI spliding towards the bottom.

Thank you! :)

Sergio

Comment: Could you post screenshots of how it looks ? Have you tried to reproduce this bug with a very simple layout ?

Comment: Here you are: https://imagizer.imageshack.us/v2/405x675q90/855/pwiob.jpg

Comment: Can you post your XAML code for this screenshot ?

Comment: This is the xaml of that first Panorama Page. The other elements you see in the screen that are not in the xaml are outside of the panorama control and placed directly in the LayoutRoot grid, I think that's why they don't get messed up.
http://pastebin.com/18eDZ2ix
Thank you for your help! :)

Comment: Ok so I looked at your code. You have a MAJOR problem in it. You try to place each and every element using different values of the "Margin" property. But you should not do that. "Margin" is to be used to make only tiny adjustments to the layout. You MUST use relative positioning to build your layout. So basically, try to start over your page, without using any margin (especially on your root Grid element), but using Grid Rows and Grid Columns, and more important "StackPanel"

Comment: If you really have trouble using that, post an image of what you want your layout to be, and I can help you get started. But the way you coded your layout right now, it is absolutely not something you want to do, and if you keep doing that, you will be living hell for your other pages ;)

Comment: Daaaamn ahahahahahah I have 212 "Margin" in total in my xaml right now, how am I supposed to do that? :S
I mean, I have already finished the UI part of my app (and that's more than 1000 xaml lines), and I have already designed all the pages I needed (in the wrong way, as you said).
I tried to edit "Grid Row" and "Grid Columns" in a Grid, to try if I could replicate the layout I got with the Margin setting, but nothing happened.
Is there a way to let all the Grids/Elements remain in the same position, by removing the "Margin" end editing another setting?
Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: What if I put the main Grid inside a Canvas (or replace the main LayoutRoot Grid with a Canvas), and set an absolute position to it? Shouldn't that fix the issue?

EDIT: Yeah! I put everything in my MainPage.xaml from the LayoutRoot on inside a Canvas, and I set Canvas.Left and Canvas.Top to 0, and now it works fine!
When I get a call the whole UI slides down to leave space for the call banner at the top of the screen, but the layout istelf remains perfect :D
I just have to adjust the position of a couple of elements, but the rest is great. Can this be considered a good way to fix that?

Comment: Well, like I said, the way you used margins will be giving you nightmares. Right now, if your fix works, good for you, but if someone has to work on your project in some time, I think he is going to kill himself :)
Maybe you can consider refactoring your pages one by one in a next version of your app (if your fix really work). If you have a very simple xaml page/control using Margins like you do in your example, post it here, and I'll explain you how to fix it

Comment: This should be simple enough :D
http://pastebin.com/LKTi2sfU
Anyway, I don't think anyone else will ever work on the app I'm writing, so that shouldn't be a problem :)
But as for me, I understand it'll be better if I learn how to design correctly ahahahah
I started coding on WP8 on my own a week ago, so that's why I did errors like those :)
Thank you again!

(I'll be happy to send you a private beta for the app I'm working on, if you send me your live ID as a private message, so you can take a look at the app and tell me what you think, I'd love that)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so, I modified the XAML you provided to give you an example
I don't have telerik installed on my machine, so I replaced them with basic controls.

As you can see, you have to imagine your layout as a grid, with rows and possibly columns, and then inside these rows, place your elements as you wish.

Since you started very recently windows phone dev, I strongly advise you to read tutorials on the basics of XAML, and layout building in XAML.

```
...<phone:PhoneApplicationPage x:Class="App_panorama_esercitazione.Encrypt"
                        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
                        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
                        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
                        xmlns:phone="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Controls;assembly=Microsoft.Phone"
                        xmlns:shell="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Shell;assembly=Microsoft.Phone"
                        FontFamily="{StaticResource PhoneFontFamilyNormal}"
                        FontSize="{StaticResource PhoneFontSizeNormal}"
                        Foreground="{StaticResource PhoneForegroundBrush}"
                        Orientation="Portrait"
                        SupportedOrientations="Portrait"
                        shell:SystemTray.IsVisible="False"
                        mc:Ignorable="d">

<!--  LayoutRoot è la griglia radice in cui viene inserito tutto il contenuto della pagina  -->
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <!--  TitlePanel contiene il nome dell'applicazione e il titolo della pagina  -->
    <StackPanel Grid.Row="0">
        <TextBlock Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextNormalStyle}" Text="Funzioni varie" />
        <TextBlock Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextTitle1Style}" Text="Decripta testo" />
    </StackPanel>

    <TextBlock Grid.Row="1"
               Margin="15"
               Text="Telerik rad button" />

    <StackPanel Grid.Row="2"
                Margin="15"
                HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                Orientation="Horizontal">

        <TextBlock Text="Telerik password" />

        <Button Width="225"
                Height="85"
                HorizontalAlignment="Right"
                VerticalAlignment="Top"
                BorderThickness="5"
                Click="Button_Click"
                Content="Decripta!"
                FontSize="25"
                FontWeight="Bold" />
    </StackPanel>

    <!--  ContentPanel - inserire ulteriore contenuto qui  -->
    <Border Grid.Row="3"
            Margin="15"
            BorderBrush="White"
            BorderThickness="2">
        <TextBlock x:Name="Decodificato"
                   Width="436"
                   Height="373"
                   FontSize="25"
                   Text="Testo decodificato[...]"
                   TextWrapping="Wrap" />
    </Border>
</Grid>
```

Comment: Ok, now I realize how wrong my designing method was ahahahah
Thank you again for your help :)
Cheers!